# Quality of Graphics3D primitives in GIFs (V11)

Tags: bugs, graphics3d, export, gif-format

**Bug introduced in V11.1 and fixed in V11.2**

What happened? Is this a regression or maybe some default options were changed?

Test case:

```
Graphics3D[Sphere[]] // Export["Test.gif", #] &
```

[image: GIF comparison]

Comparison 11.1.1 vs 10.4 on Windows 10.

Comment: Eek... any impact on the file size?

Comment: @YvesKlett `FileByteCount /@ {"11.gif", "10.gif", "11.png", "10.png"}` -> `{18493, 28635, 41518, 42317}`

Comment: About the file sizes: Dithering introduces noise to smoothen the appearance of gradients.  Noise doesn't compress well.  I would expect a dithered GIF (containing smooth gradients) to be significantly larger than a non-dithered one.  If it weren't for @ChipHurst's comment I would say that the reason to change `Automatic` to non-dithered could only be file size reduction.

Comment: @Szabolcs That would have been my guess too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I talked to the relevant developer and it turns out this is indeed a regression.

It looks as if the default `"DitheringMethod"` changed from `"FloydSteinberg"` to `None`.

Compare `"DitheringMethod"` pointing to `None`, `Automatic`, and `"FloydSteinberg"` in 10.4 and 11.1:

```
Table[Labeled[
    ImportString[ExportString[Graphics3D[Sphere[]], "GIF", "DitheringMethod" -> d]], 
    {$VersionNumber, d}, Top], 
  {d, {None, Automatic, "FloydSteinberg"}}
]
```

[image]
[image]

In 10.4:

```
$VersionNumber
```

> ```
> 10.4
> ```

```
Equal[
 ImportString[ExportString["Graphics3D"[Sphere[]], "GIF"]],
 ImportString[ExportString["Graphics3D"[Sphere[]], "GIF", "DitheringMethod" -> "FloydSteinberg"]]
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

In 11.1:

```
$VersionNumber
```

> ```
> 11.1
> ```

```
Equal[
 ImportString[ExportString["Graphics3D"[Sphere[]], "GIF"]],
 ImportString[ExportString["Graphics3D"[Sphere[]], "GIF", "DitheringMethod" -> None]]
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Was that intentional?

Comment: I don't know. Just something I observed when looking through the export options of GIF.

Comment: Thanks. Is anybody around you could ask or should I ask support? :)

Comment: I talked to the relevant developer and it turns out this is indeed a regression.

Comment: Thanks for forwarding it.